# Python 2.7: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' error while writing in file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, unicode

I know this question have been asked various time but somehow I am not getting results.

I am fetching data from web which contains a string **Elzéar**. While going to read in CSV file it gives error which mentioned in question title.

While producing data I did following:

```
address = str(address).strip()
        address = address.encode('utf8')
        return name+','+address+','+city+','+state+','+phone+','+fax+','+pumps+','+parking+','+general+','+entertainment+','+fuel+','+resturants+','+services+','+technology+','+fuel_cards+','+credit_cards+','+permits+','+money_services+','+security+','+medical+','+longit+','+latit
```

and writing it as:

```
with open('records.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
  print(type(data)) #prints <unicode>
  data = data.encode('utf8')     
  csv_file.write(id+','+data+'\n')
  status = 'OK'
  the_file.write(ts+'\t'+url+'\t'+status+'\n')
```

Generates error as:

> 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 55: ordinal
>   not in range(128)

Comment: @JavierBuzzi How is that going to solve problem? Can you give example?

Comment: Don't mix Unicode strings with UTF-8 encoded bytes. You should assemble your Unicode strings into their final form & then encode to UTF-8. You should specify the Python version you're using (in the question tags), since Python 2 & Python 3 handle Unicode differently.

Comment: @PM2Ring Updated question title. The string I am getting from web.

Comment: @JavierBuzzi: The Python 2.7 [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) does not support Unicode input, although (of course) it handles UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like (python2.7):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import codecs
...
with codecs.open('records.csv', 'a', encoding="utf8") as csv_file:
  print(type(data)) #prints <unicode>
  # because data is unicode

  csv_file.write(unicode(id)+u','+data+u'\n')
  status = u'OK'
  the_file.write(unicode(ts, encoding="utf8")+u'\t'+unicode(url, encoding="utf8")+u'\t'+status+u'\n')
```

The main idea is to work with unicode as much as possible and return str when outputing (better do not operate over str).

Comment: Awesome! worked like charm.

You opened file as unicode this is why it worked? can you elaborate?

Comment: As told in previous comments. Do not mix str and unicode when doing this python will try to do some coercion between  str and unicode, cause of some unicode error. And when you have your final unicode to must specify an appropriate charset (utf8) to ouput your result.

Comment: Aka, the "Unicode Sandwich". Decode in, encode out. Internally, use Unicodes.