# Encoding error while prettifying xml

Tags: python, encoding

I have data to put into an xml file with python 2.7, but I have this encoding error :

```
File "script.py", line 121, in buildXML
output_file.write( prettify(tickets)) 
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 2621: ordinal not in range(128)
```

My code :

```
output_file = open( 'tickets.xml', 'w' ) 
output_file.write( '<?xml version="1.0"?>' ) 
output_file.write( prettify(tickets))
output_file.close()
```

I tried some solutions found on the internet without success

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 2.7: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' error while writing in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947902/python-2-7-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xe9-error-while-writing-in)

Comment: In general, you must use one of the Unicode encodings to emit the document because element names can have any Unicode letter and using numeric character entity references isn't allowed. For example, this is a valid document that you can't use ASCII for: `<ć>&#x0109;</ć>`

Answer (score 0):

```
output_file = open('tickets.xml', 'w') 
output_file.write('<?xml version="1.0"?>') 
output_file.write(prettify(unicode('{}'.format(tickets), errors='ignore').encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
output_file.close()
```

I hope this will solve your problem for `encode` error

Comment: output_file.write(prettify(unicode(tickets, errors='ignore').encode('ascii', 'ignore')))
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Element found    ---tickets is the root of my xml document

Comment: @Dudzer can you tell me what's `tickets`

Comment: import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET ----  tickets = ET.Element("tickets")

Comment: @Dudzer I have updated code, this will work I am sure